# Custom field as a parameter

Tags: ee3, solspace-calendar

i 'm working on a project about events in a city using Solspace calendar. What i want is the user to select some data in a form (date range, category -music, theatre, etc- and area). The data are going to the results page. Everything works on the results page apart the area which is a custom text field.

My code is

```
{exp:calendar:events
    channel="events"
    category="{segment_3}"
    show_recurrences="yes"
    load_resource_consuming_data="yes"
    date_range_start="{segment_4}-{segment_5}-{segment_6}" 
    date_range_end="{segment_7}-{segment_8}-{segment_9}" 
    limit="10" paginate="both"
}
```

The area text field is "event_city2" and values can be "Athens" or "Piraeus", etc
Now, i have tried to include it inside the above code as a parameter like event_city2 ="segment_10" or calendar:event_city2 ="segment_10" or search:event_city2 ="segment_10" with no success

I saw in the solspace calendar documentation that a custom field can be a variable but not a parameter.

So i'm asking the community if there is a solution to that

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried putting the segment tag into curly brackets...?  e.g.
`event_city2="{segment_10}"`

Comment: Tried it ... does not work .. thanks for the response

Answer (score 1):

It states in the [docs](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/globals/url_segments.html#url-segment-variables) that there is hard coded limit of 9 segments. So `segment_10` will never resolve.

Comment: have removed other parameters and left only that as "{segment_2"} ... still does not work

Answer (score 1):

By its very nature, calendaring add-ons with recurring event handling like Calendar use a lot of resources to render. It may not be as much of an issue for smaller sites, but for ones with many events it becomes a major performance issue. Because of this, we kept the `{exp:calendar:events}` template tag very lean to keep it always running fast.

This unfortunately means that not all features available with `{exp:channel:entries}` are also available for `{exp:calendar:events}`. In this particular case, **custom field searching (`search:field_name="value"`) is not available at this time.**